# Camera rig with multiple AC transformers

Tags: transformer

I have 10 cameras in a rig each hooked up to a separate AC transformer.  I am looking for a way to decrease the bulk of having 10 separate transformers.  What would I have to do to achieve this?  Ideally I would like a single plug and a single box, with 10 feeds going to the various cameras.

Comment: Camera details? Transformer details? Wiring details?

Comment: 10 feeds - all switched independently or doesn't matter?

Comment: Assuming that your rig is used as a security cam system, those transformers should be there to provide isolation from mains and protecting the cameras from power surges. So it's not recommended to supply them from single source.

Comment: The would only ever be  all be switched on at the same time. Its a photography rig

They are canon Eos 500D cameras, Tranformers are Voltage and current : 7,4V - 2A

Comment: @BenP: You'll need to make it easy for those you are asking to help you. The info in your comment above belongs in the question along with links to the datasheets / specifications for the cameras and power supplies. Please edit.

Comment: Are you talking about AC in / AC out transformers or AC in / DC out power supplies? Do you have the input and output voltage and current or power ratings?

Answer (score 1):

Devices have not used actual transformers for 10 or more years. Instead, they use switching power supplies. This has made the plug pack smaller and cheaper. What you can't get around is power.

Your 10 plug packs are capable of 148 Wats of power. That may not be how much the cameras are actually consuming. What you need to understand is that if you replace the 10 with one, the one will be about the size of the 10 combined (roughly).

What you'll need is a supply that is preset to or adjusted to 7.4V and that is capable of 20 or more amps. If the supply is adjustable you'll need some way to hold the adjustment so that it doesn't accidentally get bumped. Then you'll need a wiring harness that connects all the cameras to the power supply. This either means you build something from scratch or cut the wires off the 10 you have and wire them together.

Answer (score 0):

If those cameras are in close distance to each other and the length of each power cable from the central power supply to a camera is not longer than about 2 to 3 m, you may do it. But the voltage drop from supply to camera should not be larger than about 0.1 V. Calculate the necessary cable size for the given current and the voltage drop. But you may also use two instead of one central power supplies.